# Concatenating two strings in Sql with space

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concatenate two strings having space between them.The script below concatenates but it doesn't give any space between them.

```
UPDATE INS  
set INS.UpdateBy = x.FNameTxt +''+''+''+ x.LNameTxt 
From #Insured INS
Inner Join 
(
select I.ModSystemUserId,SU.FNameTxt,SU.LNameTxt
from Insured I
inner join dbo.SystemUser SU
on I.ModSystemUserId = Su.SystemUserId
where I.InsuredId = @insuredId
) AS X
on INS.Insuredid =@insuredId
```

I am doing this `INS.UpdateBy = x.FNameTxt +''+''+''+ x.LNameTxt`

```
x.FNameTx = John
x.LNameTxt = Doe
```

result: JohnDoe i need space between them

Comment: on mysql you have to use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

Comment: "*The script below concatenates...*" - no it doesn't: the [`+`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus) operator does not perform string concatenation in SQL.

Comment: [Valid MySQL operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html) and [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Not *entirely* true - one *can* also use `||` if the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE INS  
  set INS.UpdateBy = CONCAT(x.FNameTxt,'  ',x.LNameTxt) ....
```

[**CONCAT(str1,str2,...)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)